# Usage of comment node in javascript

Tags: javascript

This may be silly question but as a JS newbie wished to know answer [Comment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Comment/Comment)  .I could not find a simple answer on SO so posing a question here.

Created a comment object...

> let Acomment = new Comment("Test");

so now a comment object is constructed , can please someone tell me **what to do next **with this Acomment object , any practical usage scenarios to broaden my thinking.

Comment: If you click through [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Comment) you'll see where it's applicable. But, like Pointy, I've never made one with JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a representation of HTML `<!-- Test -->` and it can be inserted in your document if so desired.

Why would you do this? Nobody knows for sure. Would you *ever* do this? Maybe not!

Why does it exist? Without this, there'd be parts of the DOM that could not be represented in the JavaScript domain, which would mean that there's holes in the API. It's for the sake of completeness. Every HTML element has a corresponding JavaScript representation by design.

Comment: You mentioned 'it can be inserted in your document if so desired'...then what are you referring as the 'it' ...is it <!-- Test --> or something else if you can elaborate ..thanks

Comment: Well, they're one and the same, really. The JavaScript [`Comment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Comment/Comment) node is inserted as the HTML `<!-- ... -->` accordingly, and any document with that kind of HTML will show up as a `Comment` in the JavaScript realm. They are, effectively, two different representations of the exact same thing.

Comment: You can add this to your document as you would any other DOM element, like [`Document.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/append). You can also find them when navigating through an existing document that has comments in it.

Comment: accepted ; code example: 
<html>
<body>
    <p id="p2">xxnode</p>
</body>
<script>
  let comment = new Comment("89876Test");
  document.getElementById("p2").append(comment.data);
</script>
</html>

Comment: by the way ..Also comment shows up in console.log as `<!--89876Test-->` if console.log(comment) is written.